# Angular routes empty when checked

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to get the current path of my Angular app. However, this is always returned empty.

```
  constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.route.url.subscribe(segments => {
      var currentPath = segments[0].path;
      console.log("Current Route: ", currentPath);
    });
  }
```

No matter where I navigate, this is always empty:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `this.route.snapshot.url[0].path` where `private route: ActivatedRoute`

Comment: Get this error: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Comment: If you are in dialog/modal there is no `path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get current route url  , you can use this code :

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path); 
}
```

If you want to get full url of web app . you should use this :

```js
window.location.pathname
```

Comment: I just did this which worked: bool = (window.location.pathname === "/promo") ? false : true;

Answer (score 0):

`ActivatedRoute` doesn't have a path. You should consult the router which you can inject along with the constructor.

A common way is to provide location used to navigate to the activated route but it uses additional services that you might not adhere.